# Data is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Console states the following errors when I hit the submit button on my page:

```
process.js:19 Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined
at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (process.js:19)
at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
at HTMLButtonElement.y.handle (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
```

This is my jQuery AJAX code that executes when you hit the submit button. This is my first time playing with AJAX/jQuery - not sure what is happening so if someone could help me, that'd be greatly appreciated!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#login_button').click(function()
{
    event.preventDefault();
    var formData = {
        'email'         : $('input[email=email').val(),
        'password'      : $('input[password=password').val()
    };

    $.ajax({
        type        : 'POST',
        url         : 'ajax/proclogin.php',
        data        : formData,
        dataType    : 'json'
    });

    // using the done promise callback

        if (data.success == false)
        {
            if(data.errors.email)
            {
                //toastr.error(''+data.errors.email+'', 'Oops!');
                alert('Email error');
            }
            else if(data.errors.password)
            {
                //toastr.error(''+data.errors.password+'', 'Oops!');
                alert('Password Error');
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //toastr.success('Works!', 'WooHoo!');
            alert('Works.');
        }
});
});
```

Comment: The `data` object you use in the `if` conditions is not declared anywhere. You need to either use the `success` handler function of `$.ajax`, or use a `done()`  or `then()` callback

Comment: And for your next problem, don't forget to close the brackets in the selectors where you get the values (neither have a closing `]` so you'll get null for each value).

Comment: Thank you for answering. I have updated the closed bracket but unfortunately it still seems to display "email is required" no matter what(email filled in, password field blank should prompt "password is required").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`data` object that you are using is not defined. As suggested by 'Rory McCrossan', use the ajax in below mentioned way. For detailed info, go to this link - http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

**Example**:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#login_button').click(function()
    {
        event.preventDefault();
        var formData = {
            'email'         : $('input[email=email]').val(),
            'password'      : $('input[password=password]').val()
        };

        $.ajax({
            type        : 'POST',
            url         : 'ajax/proclogin.php',
            data        : formData,
            dataType    : 'json',
            success     : function(data){
                         if (data.success == false)
                           {
                              if(data.errors.email)
                              {
                               //toastr.error(''+data.errors.email+'', 'Oops!');
                                alert('Email error');
                              }
                    else if(data.errors.password)
                    {
                        //toastr.error(''+data.errors.password+'', 'Oops!');
                        alert('Password Error');
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    //toastr.success('Works!', 'WooHoo!');
                    alert('Works.');
                }
               });
        }
     });                   
 });
```

Comment: Thank you. I revamped the code and it works flawlessly.

Comment: I am stuck on another error though. Regardless of whether the email field is filled in, it still prompts an error saying "Email is required", yet, it's filled in. Any ideas with my code above?

Comment: How are you validating email field?

Comment: The code in proclogin.php is this: if (empty($_POST['email']))
    {
        $errors['email'] = 'Email is required.';
    }

The form name and id for email is set to 'email'. Then passed to process.js

Comment: See my comment under the question.

Comment: @Archer is right. Close the brackets. Updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you both for answering. I have updated the closed bracket but unfortunately it still seems to display "email is required" no matter what(email filled in, password field blank should prompt "password is required").

Answer (score 0):

The **response** or **data** is available in the success callback of `$.ajax` call.

```
 $.ajax({
        type        : 'POST',
        url         : 'ajax/proclogin.php',
        data        : formData,
        dataType    : 'json'
    }).done(resp => {
       // You IF statements go here.
    }).fail(error => {

    });
```

Look at the docs at: [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Answer (score 0):

Model ajax function looks like this

```
$.ajax({
    url : 'wopiEditor',
    data : {
        data : data,
        reqType : "initEditFile",
        access_token : "DEADBEEFDEADBEEFDEADBEEF"
    },
    type : 'POST',
    dataType : 'text',
    success : function(response) {

    },
    error : function(request, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(request, textStatus, errorThrown);
    }
});
```

In your code, the data is defined anywhere. So it is giving error.

Answer (score 0):

```
Add success handler like this...

 $.ajax({
        type        : 'POST',
        url         : 'ajax/proclogin.php',
        data        : formData,
        dataType    : 'json',
        success: function (response) {
           console.log(response);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

concerning your issue now with validation of email and password

```
'email'         : $('input[email=email]').val(),
'password'      : $('input[password=password]').val()
```

this -> input[email=email] is targeting an input element with an "email" attribute which isnt a valid input attribute, your looking for name/type ect.

```
'email'         : $('input[name=email]').val(),
'password'      : $('input[name=password]').val()
```

so you are targeting all **input elements** that have the **name attribute** of email or password. then make sure you have name=email on your input element

```
<input type="email" name="email">
<input type="text" name="password">
```

hopefully this solution helps you

Comment: Thank you. I just clocked onto the issue. New to AJAX :)